# Strange behavior of counts on first comment to answer?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign

[My answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-create-my-own-programming-language-and-a-compiler-for-it/84282#84282) seems to have a fair amount of upvotes, call it N(>25).  I didn't think it controversial, but the first comment in response is pretty negative about the quality of the answer, and has a huge upvote count (>N-4).  I assume that means there are a bunch of folks to agree with the negative assessment.

Ignoring the answer itself, why would it be the case that the answer has a huge upvote count, and the negative remark has a huge upvote count?  The answer is getting almost exactly one vote in favor, for each upvote on the negative comment, if I interpret this data, which seems statistically strange to me.  Weirder, the differences in votes for and the negative comment count seem to have held steady at a small constant ("4?").  If I didn't think SO+friends was well built, I'd say the first-comment count was automatically tracking the positive-vote count without any human beings participating.
(That's the question: is it broken? Nah, can't be ...?)

I'd generally expect downvoters to vote against the answer, rather than upvoting the comment (but maybe they're all in violent agreement which is pretty strange at SO in my experience).
If I could see the actual for/against votes as on StackOverflow, would I see a positive vote count of 2N+4, and a negative vote count of N?   Why doesn't Programmers have the same vote display mechanism, which would let me lay my fears to rest?

Comment: The up/down votes on your answer are currently +34, -5

Comment: [How did you figure out up/down vote count?] OK, that explains my answer vote count.  Why would people upvote an extremely negative comment, but not downvote the answer itself??

Answer (score 3):

Programmers has the same "view vote counts" privilege as every other Stack Exchange site. It becomes available at [1000 reputation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-vote-counts).

As Matt Allen said, the current vote split on your answer is +34 / -5. I don't think it really means anything other than "34 people agreed enough to upvote my question and 5 thought it was worth downvoting". I wouldn't read too much into the comment upvotes, since there is no corresponding downvote to balance them out.

I think the explanation for what you're seeing is simple: it costs rep to downvote an answer and it doesn't cost anything to upvote a comment. Not now that the answer is community wiki which might even it out a bit, but even then there will be people who disagree but not strongly enough to downvote.

Comment: Wow. People worry about 1 point of rep when they cast a downvote.  OK, got the explanation; my rep on Programmer isn't high enough to see vote totals (that seems like a weird constraint).  I've had much higher rep on SO for so long, I forgot this was an rep-dependent privelege.  Thanks.